# Update text inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below is executed using server push:

```
 $('tr[name=' + device + ']').find("td[id='status']").text('STARTED');
```

when I try to access the id of the element it gives proper result

```
$('tr[name=' + device + ']').find("td[id='status']").attr('id'); // works for me
```

but when I try to update the text using html or text it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed cf">
        <thead class="cf">
        <tr>
.........
................



        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


                <tr id="car0" name="5" class="redRow">
                    <td><a href="#" style="color: white">.....</a></td>
                    <td>.....</td>
                    <td>.....</td>
                    <td>......</td>
                    <td id="5status">......</td>
                    <td>.....</td>
                    <td>.....</td>
                    <td>........</td>

                </tr>



                <tr id="car2" name="8" class="redRow">
                    <td><a href="#" style="color: white"> ....</a></td>
                    <td>......</td>
                    <td>......</td>
                    <td>......</td>
                    <td id="6status">0 km/h</td>
                    <td>........</td>
                    <td>..........</td>
                    <td>..........</td>

                </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I even tried $('#6status').text('STARTED'); but doesn't work.

Comment: The symptom (and the code) both suggest that you have more than one element with `id="status"` in your document. `id` values **must** be unique. So I suspect that the call to `text` is updating an element, just not the one you're looking at.

Comment: Can you add table html structure to question?

Comment: Firstly your code should technically be working. Check the console for errors. However, why not just use `$('#status').text('started')`? Your code implies there's multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, which is an issue in itself

Comment: The id is unique. I searched DOM. I tried $('#status').text('started') but its also not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zy6ds08h/ it's working for me. Can you add your html?

Answer (score 0):

Your td element have numbers before substring `status`.
So use selector to get element contains substring `status`. 
Read more about this selector [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)

**Solution:**

```
$('tr[name=' + device + ']').find("td[id*='status']").text('STARTED');
```

**Example:**

```js
$(function() {
 var device = '8';
 $('tr[name=' + device + ']').find("td[id*='status']").text('STARTED');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed cf">
        <thead class="cf">
        <tr>
.........
................



        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


                <tr id="car0" name="5" class="redRow">
                    <td><a href="#" style="color: white">.....</a></td>
                    <td>.....</td>
                    <td>.....</td>
                    <td>......</td>
                    <td id="5status">......</td>
                    <td>.....</td>
                    <td>.....</td>
                    <td>........</td>

                </tr>



                <tr id="car2" name="8" class="redRow">
                    <td><a href="#" style="color: white"> ....</a></td>
                    <td>......</td>
                    <td>......</td>
                    <td>......</td>
                    <td id="6status">0 km/h</td>
                    <td>........</td>
                    <td>..........</td>
                    <td>..........</td>

                </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```